# Colocar caminho do site em um include PHP

Tags: php, include

Como colocar todo o caminho do site em uma include? Por exemplo:

```
<?php
include "http://www.site.com.br/include/categorias.php";
?>
```

Tem como fazer algo parecido?

Comment: O seu exemplo não aparece

Comment: Acho que não justifica negativar algo que pode ser corrigido com uma edição simples...

Comment: O que você quer fazer exatamente? Executar o script de um outro servidor no seu?

Comment: esse exemplo é fictício!

Comment: Quero incluir um pequeno código em php em duas páginas...página de produtos e detalhes do produto.

Comment: Se você quer executar o script no teu servidor, isso não é possível, mas se você quiser o resultado, você pode usar o `curl`.

Comment: @user3081 você quer que o php execute esse arquivo ou simplesmente receba o retorno de "http://www.site.com.br/include/categorias.php" ?

Comment: receba o retorno dessa página de categorias, pois se caso eu for fazer uma manutenção futuramente, não necessite alterar duas páginas, e apenas essa página de categorias

Answer (score 5):

### Se você quer executar um PHP remoto no seu código:

Atenção: isto é um perigo, por uma série de razões, mas lá vai:

Para fazer um *include* "de verdade" com PHP, a diretiva [`allow_url_include`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/filesystem.configuration.php) precisa estar `on` no seu php.ini, assim como a diretiva [`allow_url_fopen`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/filesystem.configuration.php).

### Se quer apenas o conteúdo do resultado do URL remoto:

Se a diretiva [`allow_url_fopen`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/filesystem.configuration.php) estiver habilitada, você pode fazer uma requisição HTTP de maneira bem simples, como se o URL fosse um arquivo local:

```
$arquivo = fopen( 'http://www.exemplo.com.br/', 'r' );
if ( $arquivo ) {
   $resultado = '';
   // As 3 linhas abaixo podem ser substituidas por essa no PHP 5+
   // $resultado = stream_get_contents( $arquivo );
   while (!feof( $arquivo ) ) {
      $resultado .= fread( $arquivo , 8192 );
   }
}
fclose($file);
```

Alternativamente, se seu PHP estiver com o cURL instalado, conforme o @KaduAmaral comentou, pode fazer algo assim:

```
<?php
   $curl= curl_init();
   curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.exemplo.com.br/' );
   curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false ); // para não retornar os Headers
   curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ); // para retornar na variável
   $resultado = curl_exec( $curl );
   curl_close( $curl );

   // Processe o resultado para formatar adequadamente
   // e/ou extrair apenas as partes desejadas.
   echo $resultado;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível fazer o `include` ou `require` de arquivos fora da mesma estrutura de arquivos do site na configuração padrão do php.

Seu site deve ter uma estrutura de diretórios parecida com essa caso queira executar funções de `categorias.php`

```
.
|_ index.php
|_ categorias.php
```

No seu arquivo `index.php` faça o `include` somente do `categorias.php`

```
<?php

include "categorias.php";

echo getCategorias();
```

E o seu `categorias.php`

```
<?php

function getCategorias(){
    return "Minha Lista de Categorias";
}
```

---

Caso queira somente exibir o retorno do arquivo `categorias.php` é possível que ele esteja em um site externo, mas no arquivo `index.php` ele terá o mesmo retorno como se fosse executado no browser.

Existem duas abordagens, como `curl` conforme a resposta do @Bacco ou simplestente usando [`get_file_contents`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php)

**Nota:** é importante lembrar que a configuração do php [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) também deve estar habilitada.

`categorias.php` no site externo:

```
<?php

function getCategorias(){
    return "Minha Lista de Categorias";
}

// Aqui ele faz essa saída no browser
echo getCategorias();
```

Seu novo `index.php`

```
<?php

// Include não vai funcionar
//include "http://www.site.com.br/include/categorias.php";

// Muito menos essa função
//echo getCategorias();

// Aqui você faz a requisição
echo get_file_contents("http://www.site.com.br/include/categorias.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

Se confiar na fonte a melhor opção será

```
<iframe align=top width='135' height='60' marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 
hspace=0 vspace=0 frameborder=0 scrolling=no 
src='http://www.site.com.br/include/categorias.php'> 
</iframe>
```

onde pode regular a largura em width e a altura em height.

Quando estou a falar de "confiar na fonte" estou a falar do site de terceiros e não do código.

A pedido do @brasofilo fiz algumas pesquisas e cheguei a conclusão que falam muito sobre o assunto mas não dizem nada de concreto por isso só poderei dar a minha opinião lógica e não uma explicação pratica pois não sou programador.

Vi que foi um código desenvolvido pela Microsoft no ano de 1994 e que esteve quase a cair em desuso por ser um código com proprietário.

A minha opinião:

Quando se insere um `iframe` de uma pagina de terceiros a nossa pagina fica á mercê e por consequência os nossos utilizadores do que for injectado nessa pagina e como não temos controlo sobre ela só poderemos remover o `iframe` quando nos apercebermos, por isso a minha chamada de atenção para "Se confiar na fonte"

Comment: Seria legal se colocasse um link que explique a questão de "confiar na fonte".