# PHP: passando variáveis de sessão de um domínio para outro domínio

Tags: php, session

Temos dois projetos hospedados em diferentes domínios. Preciso passar algumas informações de um domínio para o outro, para gerar um boleto.

Foi me solicitado que enviasse variáveis de sessão para este outro domínio para geração do boleto.

Após algumas pesquisas, vi que não é possível passar dados de sessão de um domínio para outro, existe alguma solução para contornar isso?

As regras para que eu consiga recuperar a informação desejada em outro domínio são as seguintes:

1. Seto as variáveis de sessão;
2. Em seguida faço um redirecionamento para a página do outro domínio, onde ele já pega essas variáveis;
3. Carrego a informação que necessito e gero o boleto.

Comment: Esses "projetos" são em PHP?

Comment: são sim, todos os dois em php, mas em diferentes frameworks apenas.

Comment: Então só usar o include ou ou require/require_once, ja tentou?

Comment: como assim? usar o require? mas os projetos são de dominios diferentes

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Colocar caminho do site em um include PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34240/colocar-caminho-do-site-em-um-include-php)

Comment: não mesmo. tá maluco?

Comment: Já tentou passar as informações relevantes via POST ou GET? Isso que você quer fazer é muito semelhante a uma consulta de um webservice

Comment: @Leandro esses dois projetos rodam no mesmo servidor? Se sim e se tiverem controle sobre esse servidor, talvez seja possível o compartilhamento das sessões. Leia [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92702/5878). Porém, acho mais prático e garantido fazer essa comunicação através de uma requisição HTTP simples. Basta uma aplicação fazer a requisição POST, como o Jefferson comentou, para a outra aplicação enviando os dados necessários e tratando a resposta.

Comment: sim, estão no mesmo servidor.

Answer (score 1):

De fato é impossível passar variáveis de sessão de um domínio para outro de forma direta. O que não quer dizer que não haja outras formas de resolver o seu problema.

Se você tem dois domínios diferentes rodando aplicações, mesmo que seja com o mesmo código fonte, para todos os efeitos você tem dois sistemas isolados. Você tem duas formas de fazer com que eles se comuniquem:

- **Através de um banco de dados.** Se ambas as aplicações tiverem acesso à mesma base de dados, você pode escrever nas tabelas da base com uma aplicação e ler com a outra. A lógica de como isso seria feito fica a seu critério, mas fica aqui uma sugestão: escreva as variáveis de sessão da primeira aplicação na base e dispare uma requisição para uma URI da segunda aplicação que a faça ler esses dados. Recomendo apagar os dados após o uso.
- **Através de serviço.** Essa é a forma geralmente mais elegante. A aplicação que precisa receber as variáveis de sessão pode expor um serviço. A aplicação que gera as variáveis de sessão pode consumir esse serviço. Isso tem a vantagem de utilizar a forma mais padrão de comunicação entre aplicações e manter as bases de dados de ambos os sistemas isolados.

Para o segundo caso, o fluxo é o seguinte:

1. Primeira aplicação gera conjunto de valores que atualmente você
   guarda em sessão;
2. Primeira aplicação consome serviço da
   segunda, passando esses valores e a identificação do usuário;
3. A segunda aplicação guarda esses valores (em banco ou em cache),
   sempre associando um conjunto de valores a um usuário;
4. Primeira aplicação utiliza Javascript para abrir uma nova aba/janela
   da segunda aplicação;
5. Usuário loga na segunda aplicação;
6. Segunda aplicação recupera os dados do usuário que estão no banco ou
   no cache e faz o que tem que fazer com isso (no seu caso, gerar um
   boleto).