# O mesmo cabeçalho e rodapé para vários sites

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

Boa tarde!
Trabalho numa empresa que administra vários sites (joomla - em servidores diferentes). Todos com o mesmo cabeçalho e rodapé.

De época em época, precisamos alterar todos os cabeçalhos e rodapés de todos os sites.

Esse processo, até então, é feito manualmente. Pensando na agilidade desse processo de alteração, imaginei se não seria possível criar um servidor com esse material e usar algum tipo de include, pra que eu não precise alterar um por um sempre que for necessário.

Dei uma pesquisada aqui, mas não encontrei nada muito conclusivo.
Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Comment: E cada site possui um servidor diferente ou todos estão no mesmo servidor?

Comment: Estão em servidores diferentes.

Comment: E você pretende incluir em todos os sites um arquivo que se encontra em outro servidor?

Comment: @ThiagoMaciel Achei esse Post que pode te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34240/colocar-caminho-do-site-em-um-include-php ou vc pode usar um iframe também

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Acredito que sim. Gostaria de saber o que seria o ideal.

Comment: @romulohenrique A minha primeira ideia foi o iframe mesmo. Teria algum porém? Ou solução ideal?

Comment: @ThiagoMaciel , de uma olhada no linck que comentei, la ele ensina um metodo usando o cURL , dei uma lida por cima acho q ajudaria no seu problema

Comment: Cara o Joomla é todo em PHP inclusive por default ele já possui alguns includes e requires... Porque não continuar com os includes? Se vc tem um Banco para cada site ai fica complicado mesmo, mas se é só um banco vai facilitar ainda mais

Comment: O mais fácil é manter um arquivo em cada servidor mesmo e incluí-lo na página com `include`; somente automatizar o processo de enviar o novo arquivo para todos os FTPs, que é algo bastante simples.

Answer (score 0):

é só criar um arquivo XSLT, e mandar carrega-lo no body de todos htmls com o evento onload.

Comment: Poderia explicar um pouco mais ou dar um exemplo? A resposta está muito vaga

Comment: Pergunta vaga merece resposta vaga.

Answer (score 0):

Pesquisa a linguagem xslt, ela é usada para deixar arquivos xml no formato html. Então quando você mudar esse único xml ou mesmo o xslt, todas os htmls serão atualizados. Mas você tem que pesquisar mais sobre isso, não da pra explicar em uma simples resposta.